# Show a tcp video stream (from FFPLAY / FFMPEG) in an C# application

Tags: c#, video, stream, ffmpeg

I' trying to make my Parrot AR Drone 2.0 work with a Windows machine.

I have a simple C# application to control it - but now i want the video stream inside of my application.

If I execute `ffplay tcp://192.168.1.1:5555` it connects to the videostream and shows a window with the video.

How can I get this video inside of my application? Like, a simple 'frame' or 'image' that gets filled with that content?

I have never worked that much with C# so any help would be awesome.

Comment: What code do you have thus far for doing this..?

Comment: check out this link and look at the documentation it may or may not  help.. http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/

Comment: http://dronecontroller.codeplex.com/

Comment: Here is the repository - https://github.com/RobQuistNL/ARDrone-Control-.NET- i've edited some code but haven't pushed yet. Will do tonight :) 
EDIT: There is a video-streaming-code in there, but that one is for the 1.0 version of the drone. Doesn't work on the 2.0 version. I believe its an H.687 (or something like that) stream

Comment: please put some code that you had tried in-order to help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can launch the `ffplay` process and then PInvoke `SetParent` to place the player window inside your form and `MoveWindow` to position it.

To do this you would need to define the following.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

Then you can use the two native methods like so.

```
// start ffplay 
var ffplay = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = "ffplay",
                Arguments = "tcp://192.168.1.1:5555",
                // hides the command window
                CreateNoWindow = true, 
                // redirect input, output, and error streams..
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false    
            }
    };

ffplay.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
ffplay.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine(e.Data ?? "NULL", "ffplay");
ffplay.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine(e.Data ?? "NULL", "ffplay");
ffplay.Exited += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Exited", "ffplay");
ffplay.Start();

Thread.Sleep(200); // you need to wait/check the process started, then...

// child, new parent
// make 'this' the parent of ffmpeg (presuming you are in scope of a Form or Control)
SetParent(ffplay.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);

// window, x, y, width, height, repaint
// move the ffplayer window to the top-left corner and set the size to 320x280
MoveWindow(ffplay.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 320, 280, true);
```

The standard output of the `ffplay` process, the text you usually see in the command window is   handled via `ErrorDataReceived`. Setting  the `-loglevel` to something like `fatal` in the arguments passed to ffplay allows you to reduce the amount of events raised and allows you to handle only real failures.

Comment: Will try both methods tomorrow!

Comment: No worries, I also added in how you would capture the output text into managed code from the process, allowing you to handle errors etc.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you :) A lot of ARDrone flyers will thank you if this works good!

Comment: No worries at all. If you [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) people will be more likely to help you in the future too.

Comment: I still have to try it :P then i'll chose an answer. THanks!

Comment: I also tried but my form hangs. Playback continues as I hear the audio but picture is still and cannot click any widget on the form. I saw that ffplay hangs.

Comment: @MertGülsoy this is an old question but it should work as shown. The issue is probably the either the line `Thread.Sleep(200);` which is too short a time, or else ffplay is hanging for some other reason. What does the ffmpeg log output look like?

Comment: @Fraser you're right. ffplay hanging for some reason. Possibly the stream source is poor. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, You can probably just check if there is an ffplay process running via `Process.GetProcessesByName("ffplay");` and relaunch it if it has crashed. Also the ffplay process itself could be waiting for you to read its output, so you could create a separate thread to read from its standard output while you're waiting for it to exit. Without seeing the actual code/error logs it is hard to help. Maybe post your own question - I'd be happy to take a look for you.

Comment: since ffplay opens a console window first, you need to wait until ffplay.MainWindowHandle becomes not IntPtr.Zero

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried streaming with media player? Just add the control from the toolbox on the form and then add the following code to your form.cs

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "your URL";
    }
}
```

Details in the following link

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
```

Comment: well, that might work.. I'll try it tonight. But I guess this is not really a direct stream and i'll have some more latency this way. I'll get back at you tonight!

Comment: any luck with the video?

Comment: media player does not work with ffmpeg hosted stream

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;


namespace FfplayTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public Process ffplay = new Process();
        private void xxxFFplay()
        {


            ffplay.StartInfo.FileName = "ffplay.exe";

            string _argString = "-fflags nobuffer \"rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.163/live0.264\" -x 640 -y 480";
            string _newArgString = _argString.Replace("\",\"", ";");
            ffplay.StartInfo.Arguments = _newArgString;

            ffplay.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            ffplay.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            ffplay.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            ffplay.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            ffplay.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine(e.Data ?? "NULL", "ffplay");
            ffplay.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine(e.Data ?? "NULL", "ffplay");
            ffplay.Exited += (o, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Exited", "ffplay");
            ffplay.Start();
            IntPtr intPtr = ffplay.MainWindowHandle;
            Thread.Sleep(200); // you need to wait/check the process started, then...

            // child, new parent
            // make 'this' the parent of ffmpeg (presuming you are in scope of a Form or Control)
            SetParent(ffplay.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);

            // window, x, y, width, height, repaint
            // move the ffplayer window to the top-left corner and set the size to 320x280
            MoveWindow(ffplay.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 320, 280, true);


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xxxFFplay();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            try { ffplay.Kill(); }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

My Code is this, How ever it is loading ffplay but don't move in to panel or don't position it to given